# C++ Compiler Implementing Namespace

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, namespaces, implementation, name-decoration

From the C++ compiler's point of view, is namespace just a name decoration convention?  I have inspected the generated assembly listing and found that everything just looks the same except the identifiers are decorated by the namespace's name.

Comment: But what else did you expect? :) It's *name*-space, after all.

Comment: Yes. And what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, name mangling is part of the story (but the reasons for doing it have more to do with linkers rather than compilers).

However, name mangling is far from the whole story as far as the handling of namespaces in the compiler is concerned. Among other things, the compiler has to be able to figure out unqualified names, which can be non-trivial: see [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup).

Answer (score 0):

> From the C++ compiler's point of view, is namespace just a name decoration convention?

I think yes. Its just a name decoration at the end.

In order to do that compiler does lots  of things. It chooses the correct namespace(s), possibly out of many, when resolving a name.

For example,

```
namespace X
{
  void f(); //compiler chooses X only when decorating f()
  namespace Y
  {
      void f();  //compiler chooses X and Y when decorating f()
      void g()   //compiler chooses X and Y when decorating g()
      {
          f();    //which f? Compiler decorates it with both X and Y.
          X::f(); //which f? Compiler decorates it with X only.
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't namespace have a scope of some sort? You could potentially have two classes with the same name, but the namespace prevents collision.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that's what it is. The desciption can be found under name mangling:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Answer (score 0):

It is no coincidence that the first C++ compiler written by Bjarne Stroustrup was called [CFront](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront). It converted C++ code to C and fed it to a C compiler. So, I believe it is just name mangling to create unique symbols for overloading & avoid name conflicts (namespace)

Comment: CFront did not have namespaces.

Comment: @neil: I agree but the concept was there as classes with same named functions, hence they needed name mangling since C needs unique function names.